# How to extract the texture from an image onto a mesh?

Tags: textures, rendering, 3d-meshes

*(preamble: I think this fits either here or SO with computer vision tag, I chose gamedev because I think you guys are probably really good with textures and meshes, but tell me if my decision was wrong.)*

I want to accomplish the following: Given an image with an object, a 3D mesh very similar to that object, and rendering parameters that render that mesh to the exact location of this object. I want to "extract" the original texture from the image onto the mesh. (So in a later step, I could re-render the mesh from another viewpoint (of course some of the texture would be invisible/black)). My mesh has uv-coordinates for each triangle so I guess I could either "store the texture on the mesh" somehow, or directly backmap it to a 2D texture map.

So I guess what I want to do is kind of texture backmapping/remapping, kind of the inverse of what is done in game-dev when texturing objects. I was having a lot of trouble finding **any** useful information on Google about what I want to do, so I thought I'd ask here. Maybe I haven't found the right word for it yet. I think there's probably quite a lot of "stuff" involved because pixel in the original image won't exactly correspond to a location on the mesh.

Comment: The technique is called *projective texturing*. Essentially, you draw the object "behind" the texture as though it was a projector-style transparency.

Comment: If you want to permanently bake a number of textures from different viewing angles onto the same model, it may be easier to do so within a modeling program. Most of them should allow you to perform an *orthogonal unwrap* of the model. You will have the opportunity to define *seams* where the edges of different textures will need to meet cleanly.

Comment: Blender is free, does all of the above, and, aside from being Eclipse-based, is also great (good enough).

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I will need it for a lot of images with command-line input and integrate it into existing software, so a program like Blender is not an option.

Comment: I don't think I need _orthogonal unwrap_ - my mesh already has uv coordinates.